Just want to ask if this is the best way to do this for speed and Less GET request Rn its around 36 RQ, it finds top 10 holders % excludes dex & Pump
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const splToken = require("@solana/spl-token");
async function main() {
const rpcEndpoint1 = "";
const wsEndpoint1 = "";
const rpcEndpoint2 = "";
const wsEndpoint2 = "";
const connection1 = new web3.Connection(rpcEndpoint1, { wsEndpoint: wsEndpoint1 });
const connection2 = new web3.Connection(rpcEndpoint2, { wsEndpoint: wsEndpoint2 });
const tokenMintAddress = "4CyNYFoLWeVfLZiXBr1L49et5MpQxsF8TDbnzEu2M1Si";
const pumpFunAccountAddress = "6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P";
const skipAddresses = [
"5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
"AC5RDfQFmDS1deWZos921JfqscXdByf8BKHs5ACWjtW2",
"u6PJ8DtQuPFnfmwHbGFULQ4u4EgjDiyYKjVEsynXq2w",
"5PAhQiYdLBd6SVdjzBQDxUAEFyDdF5ExNPQfcscnPRj5",
"BbHG9GvPActFGogv3iNrpDAj4qpXr8t3jF16uGxXcKci",
"A77HErqtfN1hLLpvZ9pCtu66FEtM8BveoaKbbMoZ4RiR",
"GThUX1Atko4tqhN2NaiTazWSeFWMuiUvfFnyJyUghFMJ",
"675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
"5quBtoiQqxF9Jv6KYKctB59NT3gtJD2Y65kdnB1Uev3h",
"CAMMCzo5YL8w4VFF8KVHrK22GGUsp5VTaW7grrKgrWqK",
"JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4",
"LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo",
"6FEVkH17P9y8Q9aCkDdPcMDjvj7SVxrTETaYEm8f51Jy",
"ASTyfSima4LLAdDgoFGkgqoKowG1LZFDr9fAQrg7iaJZ",
"BmFdpraQhkiDQE6SnfG5omcA1VwzqfXrwtNYBwWTymy6",
"43DbAvKxhXh1oSxkJSqGosNw3HpBnmsWiak6tB5wpecN",
"45ruCyfdRkWpRNGEqWzjCiXRHkZs8WXCLQ67Pnpye7Hp",
"AobVSwdW9BbpMdJvTqeCN4hPAmh4rHm7vwLnQ5ATSyrS",
"JUP4Fb2cqiRUcaTHdrPC8h2gNsA2ETXiPDD33WcGuJB",
"jupoNjAxXgZ4rjzxzPMP4oxduvQsQtZzyknqvzYNrNu",
"FLUXubRmkEi2q6K3Y9kBPg9248ggaZVsoSFhtJHSrm1X",
"PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY",
"whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc",
"2wT8Yq49kHgDzXuPxZSaeLaH1qbmGXtEyPy64bL7aD3c",
"CbYf9QNrkVgNRCMTDiVdvzMqSzXh8AAgnrKAoTfEACdh",
"9WzDXwBbmkg8ZTbNMqUxvQRAyrZzDsGYdLVL9zYtAWWM",
"5tzFkiKscXHK5ZXCGbXZxdw7gTjjD1mBwuoFbhUvuAi9",
"FWznbcNXWQuHTawe9RxvQ2LdCENssh12dsznf4RiouN5",
"JCNCMFXo5M5qwUPg2Utu1u6YWp3MbygxqBsBeXXJfrw",
"BmFdpraQhkiDQE6SnfG5omcA1VwzqfXrwtNYBwWTymy6",
"FxteHmLwG9nk1eL4pjNve3Eub2goGkkz6g6TbvdmW46a",
"H8sMJSCQxfKiFTCfDR3DUMLPwcRbM61LGFJ8N4dK3WjS",
"CPK8fQYShAmERZmysQRAGWPvV5qs3AvazQsiR9ctC6ED",
"2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm",
"GJRs4FwHtemZ5ZE9x3FNvJ8TMwitKTh21yxdRPqn7npE",
];
try {
const [mintPublicKey, tokenSupply] = await Promise.all([
new web3.PublicKey(tokenMintAddress),
connection1.getTokenSupply(new web3.PublicKey(tokenMintAddress)),
]);
const skipTokenAccounts = await getSkipTokenAccounts(connection1, mintPublicKey, skipAddresses);

const [largestAccountsFromEndpoint1, largestAccountsFromEndpoint2] = await Promise.all([
  connection1.getTokenLargestAccounts(mintPublicKey),
  connection2.getTokenLargestAccounts(mintPublicKey),
]);

const largestAccounts = largestAccountsFromEndpoint1.value.concat(largestAccountsFromEndpoint2.value);

const pumpFunFilteredAccounts = await Promise.all([
  filterAccountsByOwner(connection1, largestAccounts.slice(0, largestAccounts.length / 2), new web3.PublicKey(pumpFunAccountAddress)),
  filterAccountsByOwner(connection2, largestAccounts.slice(largestAccounts.length / 2), new web3.PublicKey(pumpFunAccountAddress)),
]);

const filteredAccounts = pumpFunFilteredAccounts.flat().filter(
  (account) => !skipTokenAccounts.includes(account.address.toBase58())
);

console.log("Token Address:", tokenMintAddress);
console.log("Total Token Supply:", tokenSupply.value.uiAmountString);
console.log("Top 10 Token Holders (excluding Dex & Cex & Pump.fun Bond):");

const uniqueAccounts = [...new Set(filteredAccounts.map(account => account.address.toBase58()))];
let totalPercentage = 0;

for (const [index, address] of uniqueAccounts.entries()) {
  if (index >= 10) break; // Exit the loop after printing the first 10 accounts

  const account = filteredAccounts.find(acc => acc.address.toBase58() === address);
  const percentage = (account.uiAmount / tokenSupply.value.uiAmount) * 100;
  totalPercentage += percentage;

  console.log(`Account ${index + 1}:`);
  console.log("  Address:", account.address.toBase58());
  console.log("  Amount:", account.uiAmountString);
  console.log("  Percentage of Total Supply:", percentage.toFixed(2) + "%");
}

console.log(`Total Percentage held by Top 10 Accounts (excluding Dex & Cex & Pump.fun Bond):`, totalPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%");

} catch (error) {
console.error("Error:", error);
}
}
async function getSkipTokenAccounts(connection, mintPublicKey, skipAddresses) {
const accountPublicKeys = skipAddresses.map((address) => new web3.PublicKey(address));
const tokenAccounts = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(new web3.PublicKey(skipAddresses[0]), {
mint: mintPublicKey,
});
const skipTokenAccounts = tokenAccounts.value
.filter((account) => accountPublicKeys.some((publicKey) => publicKey.equals(account.pubkey)))
.map((account) => account.pubkey.toBase58());
return skipTokenAccounts;
}
async function filterAccountsByOwner(connection, accounts, ownerPublicKey) {
const tokenAccountOwners = accounts.map((account) => account.address);
const accountInfos = await connection.getMultipleAccountsInfo(tokenAccountOwners);
const filteredAccounts = await Promise.all(
accounts.map(async (account, index) => {
const accountInfo = accountInfos[index];
if (accountInfo === null || !accountInfo.owner.equals(splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)) {
return null;
}
  const tokenAccountInfo = splToken.AccountLayout.decode(accountInfo.data);
  const tokenAccountOwner = new web3.PublicKey(tokenAccountInfo.owner);

  const ownerAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(tokenAccountOwner);
  if (ownerAccountInfo === null || ownerAccountInfo.owner.equals(ownerPublicKey)) {
    return null;
  }

  return account;
})

);
return filteredAccounts.filter((account) => account !== null);
}
main();
